# How to use both q and s commands in sed at the same time?

Tags: sed

I'm trying to use `q` command in sed (to mimic `head -n` and only get the first few lines) and then `s/` to substitute only on those lines a pattern.

If I omit the first expression, the substitution does exactly what I want, but when I try to apply the substitution only on the first line, only the first substitution takes place. I'm using sed and not head because I'd like to use the `-i` command later.

```
sed -e '2q' -e 's/\([0-9]\{4\}[[:space:]]\)\{3\}/XXXX XXXX XXXX /g' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the expressions matters. Here is an example:

```
cat file
a
a
a
a

< file sed '2q; s/a/b/g'
b
a

< file sed 's/a/b/g; 2q'
b
b
```

So you have to quit **after** you have replaced the second line. Currently you quit before applying the expression for the substitution. Or if you prefer the `-e` syntax:

```
< file sed -e 's/a/b/g' -e '2q'
```

---

A slighly different case:

If you want to apply a substitution only for the first 2 lines, but print the whole file, probably using `-i` together to do it in-place, you can do this:

```
< file sed '1,2 s/a/b/g' file
b
b
a
a
```

We match a line-range, `1,2` and for that range only, we execute the expression following. If we have many expressions to run for this range, we enclose them inside `{}`, like this:

```
< file sed '1,2{s/a/b/g; s/c/d/g;}' file
```

Comment: For some reason this never crossed my mind.Thank you !

Comment: Note that you don't need the braces if you only run one command on that address range. (`sed '1,2 s/a/b/g'` would be enough).

Comment: I updated with both syntaxes, thanks @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 0):

Don't sacrifice your software for the sake of `-i`. Doing `head -n file > tmp && mv tmp file` is just not a big deal and it's what sed is doing internally. Also, just like GNU sed has `-i`, GNU awk has `-i inplace` and will generally let you write a clearer and easier to enhance script than trying to do anything other than a simple `s/old/new/` with sed.

It's not clear whether you want to modify all lines and only print the first 2 or print all lines but only modify the first 2 or something else so here's a couple of possibilities:

1. Only print the first 2 input lines and modify both of them:

```
awk '{gsub(/\([0-9]{4}[[:space:]]\){3}/,"XXXX XXXX XXXX "); print} NR==2{exit}' file
```

2. Print all input lines but only modify the first 2 of them:

```
awk 'NR<=2{gsub(/\([0-9]{4}[[:space:]]\){3}/,"XXXX XXXX XXXX ") {print}' file
```

and with GNU awk for "inplace" editing like with GNU `sed -i` it'd just be:

```
awk -i inplace '...' file
```

Comment: I really appreciate your feedback, this was an assignment so we were "forced" to use sed, I also find awk more intuitive. I thought -i from sed was doing it while iterating through the files (so more efficient), never knew it was creating a temporary file, thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: Yeah, all the tools that claim to do "inplace" editing use a temp file behind the scenes except for `ed` which reads the whole file into memory before it starts working on it (which you can also do with any awk).